# How to retrieve data from sql by List<> instead of data table?

Tags: sql, database, list, data-recovery, data-retrieval

How to retrieve data from Database by ( List<> ) instead of data table?

How can I do this?

Comment: show some code you have tried

Comment: Hint - You need to map the class properties to the column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. create a class emulating your table
2. declare the list
3. retrieve data and bind it to the list
4. display your data

   public class myListClass
   {
      public string myListClassItem1{ set; get; }
      public string myListClassItem2{ set; get; }
      public string myListClassItem3{ set; get; }
   }

   List items = new List();

   while (reader.Read())
   {
      items.Add(new myListClass(reader["Item1"].ToString(), 
                       reader["Item2"].ToString(),
                       reader["Item3"].ToString()));
   }

   myDataGrid.DataSource = items;

   myDataGrid.DataBind();